# Citations change from numbers to bold if I add another citation to bib file

Tags: biblatex

I'm new to LaTex and I'm trying to understand how to create citations.
I have a `mybib.bib` file with 1 citation. I also have a `main.tex` file with the following citation packages:

```
\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

Currently I'm creating a citation with `Recent approaches \cite{author1}` and this outputs `Recent approaches [1]` which is what I want.
However, when I add another citation to the `bib` file:

```
@article{osti_1333570,
title = {Reynolds averaged turbulence modelling using deep neural networks with embedded invariance},
author = {Ling, Julia and Kurzawski, Andrew and Templeton, Jeremy},
abstractNote = {There exists significant demand for improved Reynolds-averaged Navier–Stokes (RANS) turbulence models that are informed by and can represent a richer set of turbulence physics. This paper presents a method of using deep neural networks to learn a model for the Reynolds stress anisotropy tensor from high-fidelity simulation data. A novel neural network architecture is proposed which uses a multiplicative layer with an invariant tensor basis to embed Galilean invariance into the predicted anisotropy tensor. It is demonstrated that this neural network architecture provides improved prediction accuracy compared with a generic neural network architecture that does not embed this invariance property. Furthermore, the Reynolds stress anisotropy predictions of this invariant neural network are propagated through to the velocity field for two test cases. For both test cases, significant improvement versus baseline RANS linear eddy viscosity and nonlinear eddy viscosity models is demonstrated.},
doi = {10.1017/jfm.2016.615},
journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
number = ,
volume = 807,
place = {United States},
year = {2016},
month = {10}
}
```

this changes to ``Recent approaches **author1**`

I don't know if I should add my code here because I have 40+ pages. Please let me know if there's anything else that I need to add to my question (again, I'm new in this community).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble with your bibliography, you should always check the `.blg` file. That file contains the log written by the bibliography program Biber. (On Windows machines `.blg` files may wrongly be classified as 'performance monitor' files or some such, but they are simple text files you can open with your favourite editor.) If something is wrong with your `.bib` file, it should be mentioned in the `.blg` file.

And indeed

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{osti_1333570,
title = {Reynolds averaged turbulence modelling using deep neural networks with embedded invariance},
author = {Ling, Julia and Kurzawski, Andrew and Templeton, Jeremy},
doi = {10.1017/jfm.2016.615},
journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
number = ,
volume = 807,
place = {United States},
year = {2016},
month = {10}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,osti_1333570}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

complains as follows

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'Namenlosds-46.blg'
[125] biber-MSWIN64:340> INFO - === 
[171] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'Namenlosds-46.bcf'
[303] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
[323] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[335] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Namenlosds-46.bib' for section 0
[406] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[414] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Namenlosds-46.bib'
[449] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Moritz\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_5wIq\df80c46ae0fa8bae748809bbe02c8ab5_10072.utf8, line 6, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name) or quoted string ({...} or "...")
[449] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

The important message is the `ERROR`, which tells you that lines 6 of your `.bib` file is faulty (note that often errors are only reported a few lines after they were made, so always check a few lines above the reported line as well). Line 6 is

```
number = ,
```

This is a syntax error. You must always give a value on the right-hand side of an equal sign. If you don't have a value for the field, just drop it.

Your entry should look like this

```
@article{osti_1333570,
  title   = {Reynolds Averaged Turbulence Modelling
             Using Deep Neural Networks With Embedded Invariance},
  author  = {Ling, Julia and Kurzawski, Andrew and Templeton, Jeremy},
  doi     = {10.1017/jfm.2016.615},
  journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
  volume  = 807,
  year    = {2016},
  month   = {10},
  pages   = {155-166},
}
```

with no `number` field at all.

---

BTW This is not a peculiarity of Biber's parsing of `.bib` files. BibTeX would have complained as well

```
You're missing a field part---line 6 of file Namenlosds-46.bib
 : number = 
 :          ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

Comment: I don't have a `.blg` file though. But thanks for the help! I removed that `number` line and it works

Comment: @Penguin If you ran Biber you should have a `.blg` file (unless you run a tool to clean up after compile runs, which is usually a bad idea as it will hide information like this and cause subsequent runs to take longer). Some operating systems (Windows) hide the file extension when the file type is known and as Windows recognises `.blg` as "performance monitor" files that might result in the extension not being shown. When working with LaTeX I strongly recommend you "unhide" file extensions.